# Business Objects-- Properties Tab is blank

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to build a report in Business Objects XI 2.0. I can place the data from the "Data" tab into the report, but cannot then view the properties of that data. When I click on the "Properties" tab on the left side (from "Data", "Templates", "Map", "Properties"), nothing shows up-- the tab is completely blank. A co-worker logged onto my computer and had the same result, even though it usually works on his, indicating this is some setting on my machine. Any thoughts on what could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you have an installed version of Java that is newer than Java 6.  I am using Business Objects XI 3.1 and I just had the same problem because I was auto-upgraded to Java 7.  When I downgraded back to Java 6 the properties window began working again.  You may actually need to downgrade even further to Java 1.4.2 since that is the version of Java supported by XIR2.